# как боту отправить видео в чат

Tags: python, telebot

```
при реализации кода:
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'ТЕКСТ СООБЩЕНИЯ')
video = open('видео.mp4', 'rb')
bot.send_video(message.chat_id, video, timeout=10)
выходит ошибка: bot.send_video(message.chat_id, video, timeout=10)
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'chat_id'
```

Comment: попробуйте вместо `message.chat_id` написать `message.chat.id`

Comment: это telebot или aiogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас опечатка в строке

```py
bot.send_video(message.chat_id, video, timeout=10)
```

Нужно заменить `message.chat_id` на `message.chat.id`:

```py
bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video, timeout=10)
```

Короче, это просто опечатка. Объект `message` не имеет свойства `chat_id`, но имеет `chat.id`.